# Wait for a method in an event chain to finish and return data

Tags: c#, multithreading, methods, event-handling

**What I have:**
I have a web request method `ClientWebRequest()` which executes a threaded method `GetData()` to do some data processing which executes a method  `DataReceived()` through an event handler when it's done and pass the data to it.

**What I want to do:**
What I would like to do is to notify the web request method `ClientWebRequest()` when  `DataReceived()` is called so `ClientWebRequest()` itself can return data to the client, I'm unable to do so as I do not know how to "hook" the web method to trace what happens when `DataReceived()` is finally triggered and data is received.

```
void ClientWebRequest()
{
    GetData() // using a thread
}

void GetData()
{
    Object stockData = doWorkAndGetData();
   //Do some work then notify DataReceived() when all is done with stockData passed to it
}

void DataReceived()
{
    //What I want to do here at this point is to notify ClientWebRequest() and pass stockData back to it
}
```

Comment: Could you please show a minimal and complete example of your code? Right now you aren't even showing the add handler code nor any signatures. Right now you're asking us to guess what the answer might look like.

Comment: There is no code in DataReceived() and ClientWebRequest(), that was my  point, I do not know how to handle the code in there, the event handling code between GetData() and DataReceived() is irrelevant to the question

Comment: Please make the effort of writing the code that can request data and code that can handle it. I understand you don't know how to wait for the event chain to finish and return the data, but if you could show us how you are requesting the data and how you anticipate handling it then we can have a crack at showing you the answer. Otherwise it's hard to give you a concrete answer.

Comment: Had you given enough detail when you first posted your question you probably would have had answers by now.

Comment: Use a WaitHandle class object.  I usually use a the WaitOne() method.  See following webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @jdweng Yes that worked please post this as an answer and I will accept it.